# can i use function as parameter for mysql_close(function);

Tags: mysql, function

I've a function

```
function connect
{
$c = MySQL_connect('db','ss','nn');
if(!$c)
die();
}
```

now can i use 
    MySQL_close(connect());
to close the connection because i have to use many connection inside one function and many database.

Comment: `mysql_query` and related functions are an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$conn1 = mysql_connect( ... );
$conn2 = mysql_connect( ... );

// any code here...

mysql_close($conn1);
mysql_close($conn2);
```

Do you use PHP? Mysql_... functions are deprecated in PHP. Use Mysqli or PDO instead. Mysqli has an API which is very similar to the old Mysql extension.

**UPDATES**

Comment: I will write 'mysqli' instead of 'mysql'. My examples are in procedural style for simplicity.

- A function can also return with a connection.
- If you use multiple databases, then you can switch between these: `mysqli_db_select("other_db");`.
- If you use inter-schema queries, then use of fully prefixed table names is a better choice: `mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM db1.users UNION SELECT * FROM db2.users");`
- The best option is configuration based connection handling. Place your connection setting maps (or *dsn* -s, supported by PDO and many DBAL libraries) in configuration files, and load it in creation time. This is a simplified example:

  ```
  function loadDbConfiguration($name) {
      $configs = yaml_parse( ... );
      if (array_key_exists($name, $configs)) {
          return $configs[$name];
      } else {
          // throw any exception or do something other what you prefer
      }
  }

  function getConnection($name) {
      static $connections;
      if (is_null($connections)) {
          $connections = array();
      }

      if (array_key_exists($name, $connections)) {
          return $connections[$name];
      }

      $config = loadDbConfiguration($name);
      if (($conn=@mysqli_connect(  [use $config here...]  ))!==false) {
          $connections[$name] = $conn;
          return $conn;
      } else {
          // throw any exception or do something other what you prefer
      }
  }

  function closeConnection($name) {
      // do not forget to add error handlings
      mysqli_close(getConnection($name));
  }

  $defaultConn = getConnection("default");
  $site1Conn = getConnection("site1");

  // any code here...

  // later...
  $myDefaultConn = getConnection("default"); // will same as $defaultConn
  $site2Conn = getConnection("site2");

  // at end:
  closeConnection("default");
  closeConnection("site1");
  closeConnection("site2");
  ```

  `

Comment: thx for rply  but, m using function to make connection, in a single page i've to use diffrnt connection many time, so the approach is that, if any changes made to the function connect() will appply to all. that's it.